# Multiple assignment of sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix in MATLAB which dimensions are: `8970240 x 8970240 = L x L`. Let's call it `M`.

I have to assign to a lot of elements in the matrix the value of 1, for example, given the pair of index `i` and `j`: `M(i, j) = 1`.

I have indices where I want to perform the assignment stored in vectors, this is:

- One dimension vector `V1` stores the row indices (i's).
- One dimension vector `V2`stores the column indices (j's).

Now, the issue is that the length of `V1` (7004160) is different to the length of `V2` (6389760). Which also returns a lot of nonzero elements in my sparse matrix, a total of `7004160 x 6389760 = 44754901401600 = A` nonzero elements.

I have tried to construct `M` this way:

`M = sparse(V1, V2, ones(A), L, L)`

But it does not work...

Does anybody know how to get around it?

Comment: `v1` and `v2` cannot be different sizes! if they are `i` and `j`, what happens when you run out of `v2`? `M(v1(7004160) ,  ?????? ) =1`

Comment: I know, that is why I am asking for help. Here is the thing is in V1 I have stored the row indices, let's say, I have 1, 5 and 12, for example. Then in V2 I have stored the column indices, let's say, I have 3 and 65. I need to assign one to the following pairs: `M(1, 3) , M(1, 65) , M(5, 3), M(5, 65) , M(12, 3) and M(12, 65)`. I honestly do not know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: The answer give will work for you. However, if my calculations are not wrong, you are building a matrix with sparsity of 45%. This matrix, built as a `sparse` data type, will take more memory that if you were to fill it completely, as a sparse matrix needs to store 3 values for each non-zero, 2 indices and 1 value.

Comment: I know is not that sparse hahaha, the thing is that I have to implement and algorithm in which I have to update large matrices and I was expecting I could make it faster using matrix operations, otherwise I am afraid I would take days to run the algorithm, I have not even achieved to complete one step on the iterative process...

Comment: 1) By making the matrix sparse (in this case) you are making the algorithm slower, as it needs more memory than if it were dense. 2) Linear algebra at this scale is not necessarily faster than a loop, just by memory management you lose a significant chunk on time. You seem to have the XY problem, where you are asking about an attempted solution rather than the real problem you have

Comment: Indeed, this is an XY problem. Please post a new question regarding your original problem. This approach will never work. You have `length(v1)*length(v2)` = 44 billion (trillion in US English) elements to set. This would need 40 terabytes just for storing the non-zero elements with 1 byte each (not even their positions).

Comment: I'll do that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient method, but you can do this by constructing new vectors which contain your entire list of indice pairs.

```
W1 = repmat(V1,length(V2),1); %repeat whole vector
W2 = repelem(V2,length(V1)); %repeat each element so it matches with each V1 element
```

Substitute `W1,W2` into your expression for M in place of `V1,V2`

If you aren't constrained to only store M in sparse format,

```
M = zeros(L);
M(V1,V2) = 1;
```

will give the same matrix. (And as @AnderBiguri commented this may actually use less memory *in this particular case*)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution, nonetheless, I run out of memory with those operations too: `Error using repmat
Requested 11415217766400x1 (85050.0GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays
greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size
limit or preference panel for more information.`